# Вид сказуемого?

Tags: синтаксис

Какой частью речи является слово "нет"? И какой тогда это вид сказуемого? 
В предложении"Сел, чтобы расслабиться?" сказуемое составное глагольное (потому что инфинитив) или всё-таки простое глагольное?
В предложении "Яблони в цвету" сказуемое составное именное?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Слово ***нет*** может быть частицей, а также употребляется **в функции сказуемого**  [http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=нет&all=x](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82&all=x)

**Нет** времени. **Не было** времени.  Это безличные предложения, они имеют отрицательно-бытийное значение. ***Нет*** ― уникальное слово (= не есть), ***не было*** ― безличная форма глагола *быть* в роли сказуемого (**простого глагольного**).

2)   ***Сел, чтобы расслабиться?*** Главный член безличного инфинитивного предложения выражен **независимым инфинитивом.** Это особый вид сказуемого (не относится к обычной классификации).

3) В двусоставном предложении ***Яблони в цвету*** (= яблони цветут)  **составное именное сказуемое** (сравнить: Яблони были в цвету). Также это может быть односоставным назывным предложением, если считать **в цвету** несогласованным определением.